# Consider the function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\log_e(2+x)-x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}},x>0.$ Is $f(x)$ continuous at $x=1$ ? Justify your answer

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

Consider the function $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{
\log_e(2+x)-x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}}\;\;,\quad x>0\,.$

Is $f(x)$ continuous at $x=1$ ? Justify your answer. Show that $f(x)$ does not vanish anywhere in the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and indicate the points where $f(x)$ changes its sign.

My solution goes like this:

> We have, $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\log_e(2+x)-x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}}\;\;,\quad x>0\,.$$ Now, $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\log_e(2+x)-x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}}=\\=-\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {-\log_e(2+x)+x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}}.$$ Applying L'Hospital's rule , when $x> 1,$ we get, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {-\log_e(2+x)+x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}}=\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {2x^{2n}\log x\sin x}{2x^{2n}\log x}=\sin x.$$ Thus, $f(x)=-\sin x.$ Next, if $x<1$ then $x^{2n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, and hence, $f(x)=\log(2+x).$ Finally, if $x=1$ then, $f(x=1)=\frac{\log 3-\sin 1}{2}.$ Now, we verify the continuity at $x=1.$ Now, $\lim_{x\to 1_+}f(x)=-\sin 1$ and $\lim_{x\to 1_-}f(x)=\log 3$. Thus, $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1.$ Again, it's given in the definition of $f(x)$ that $x>0$ and in the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}],$ which requires the examination, we should exclude $x=0$, so the interval to examine is $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}].$  Now, this is the first quadrant and $\sin x>0$ in the 1st quadrant and this essentially establishes the fact that $f(x)$ doesnot vanish here. From the properties of sine function, $f(x)$ changes sign between the 2nd quadrant and 3rd quadrant i.e the sign is retained in 1st and 2nd quadrant while the opposite sign appears in the 3rd and 4th quadrant **when $x>1$.** If $x<1$, then $f(x)=\log (2+x)$ is positive. If $x=1$ then $f(x)$ is easily verified positive.

Is the above solution correct? If not, where is it going wrong?

(*An edited solution after the clarifications by Thomas Andrews*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possible cases.

**Case 1:**

If $\;0<x<1\,,\;$ then $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^{2n}=0\;,\;$ hence ,

$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log_e(2+x)-x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}}=\log_e(2+x)\,.$

**Case 2:**

If $\;x=1\,,\;$ then $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^{2n}=1\;,\;$ hence ,

$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log_e(2+x)-x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}}=\dfrac{\log_e3-\sin1}2>0\,.$

**Case 3:**

If $\;x>1\,,\;$ then $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^{2n}=+\infty\;,\;$ moreover ,

$\begin{align}f(x)&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log_e(2+x)-x^{2n}\sin x}{1+x^{2n}}=\\&= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x^{2n}\left[\frac{\log_e(2+x)}{x^{2n}}-\sin x\right]}{x^{2n}\left[\frac1{x^{2n}}+1\right]}=\\&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\frac{\log_e(2+x)}{x^{2n}}-\sin x}{\frac1{x^{2n}}+1}=\dfrac{0-\sin x}{0+1}=-\sin x\,.\end{align}$

Consequently, we get that

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\log_e(2+x)&\text{if }\;0<x<1\\\\\dfrac{\log_e3-\sin1}2>0&\text{if }\;x=1\\\\-\sin x&\text{if }\;x>1\end{cases}$

$f(x)\;$ is not continuos at $\;x=1\;$ because

$\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\log_e(2+x)=\log_e3\;,$

$\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}\big(\!\!-\!\sin x\big)=-\sin1\;,$

but $\;\log_e3\neq f(1)=\dfrac{\log_e3-\sin1}2\neq-\sin1\,.$

Moreover ,

$f(x)\,$ does not vanish anywhere in the interval $\,\left]0,\frac{\pi}2\right]\,$ because

$f(x)=\log_e(x+2)>\log_e2>0\;\;$ for any $\;x\in\,]\,0,1[\;,$

$f(1)=\dfrac{\log_e3-\sin1}2>0\;,$

$f(x)=-\sin x<0\;\;$ for any $\;x\in\left]1,\frac{\pi}2\right]\,.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! So my solution is correct , right?

Comment: @Franklin, you should write that $\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f(x)=-\sin 1\,,$ not $\sin1\,.$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo! I have fixed it. All good with my solution, now ? 

Comment: @Franklin, yes, it seems correct now, but why have you applied L'Hospital's rule and calculated derivatives if there exists a simpler way to get the result of the limit ? Look at my answer and see how I have done it. Moreover, L'Hospital's rule is generally used with functions of a real variable $x$ but $n$ is not real indeed it is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comment, L'hopitals is not justified at $x=1$

Consider that $x^{2n}\rightarrow 0$ when $|x|<1,$ and $x^{2n}\rightarrow\infty$ when $|x|>1.$ So for $|x|<1$ we have $f(x)\rightarrow\log(2+x),$ and for $|x|>1$ we have $f(x)\rightarrow\sin(x).$

Comment: No, derivatives are taken correctly it's just the reason that Thomas Andrews pointed out, not just valid for two cases. Otherwise it's correct.

Comment: Oh i see,derivative wrt n indeed

Comment: Yup ;).............

Comment: @NickMendler Thanks a lot! Mind taking a look at my edited solution ?

Comment: No problem :) It looks good, a very minor typo, you say "Applying L'hopitals rule, when x$\geq1,$" but really you mean when $x>1$

Comment: @NickMendler Thanks a lot! I fixed that typo. Thank you!